# Finding the R.E.F of an augmented matrix in a multiple choice exam

Tags: linear-algebra

If I am given an augmented matrix and asked to fin it's reduced echelon form in a multiple choice paper, i.e, I am given some ref's and asked which one is the corresponding one for the augmented matrix how would I go about doing it? Since it is a multiple choice question is there another way of finding which one is its ref apart from actually working it out using the Gaussian elimination because in a multiple choice exam that might be too time consuming.

Also is reduced echelon form the same as reduced row echelon form?

Answer (score 2):

Row echelon form matrices do not require the leading $1$'s to be the only non-zero elements of their columns, so there might be entries above them. Consequently, the row echelon form of a matrix is not unique, whereas the reduced row echelon form is.

As for how to answer the question more quickly, note that as you row reduce you may be able to discount certain of the multiple choices because you may see, for instance, that you have a leading $1$ in the second column and options a) and b) do not. Then it might be possible to determine the answer without fully reducing.

Also, if your matrix comes from a system of equations, you could also try checking which of the RREF's you are given actually provide a solution to that system.